# Create and save an 'R-file' like one does for m-files in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab

I'm brand new to R, but proficient with Matlab.  The following is probably a very silly question.

In Matlab one writes a program or function and then saves it as an m-file, sat myfile.m, in Matlab's directory.  Suppose that myfile.m takes numeric inputs.  Then to use the file, one simply types, say, myfile(5) and the result is returned.

**Question**:  *How does one save a function or program written in R, and then recall it for future use*?

Basically, I want to start using R and to transfer a significant amount of my personal library of Matlab m-files into R, but no matter how much R documentation I read, I simply can't find how to save in the R directory a program or function that I have written in R, and then recall it for future use.

In other words I would like to recreate my Matlab file library in R, with the same file naming system etc.

Comment: In R you can write functions inline, no need to make a mess with separate files like in matlab. In R you can just make one source file for all related functions and then import it later on.

Comment: CV isn't the place to be asking questions about how to use R: CRAN, not surprisingly, has a lot of useful documentation, e.g. ["Writing R scripts"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Lemon-kickstart/kr_scrpt.html). Most people like to use an IDE such as [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) with [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/), or [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to write the function you want to save in a text file in R's working directory e.g. the function `myFunction` in the file myFunction.R. Then in R, you load the function into your environment by calling `source(myFunction.R)`, then you call `myFunction(...)` as normal.

Comment: Thanks.  I've learnt that in RStudio it's very easy: one just creates and saves scripts in the working directory from the editor or script window.  Actually using RStudio seems nearly identical to using Matlab.